# How do I make git use my git username (git config user.name) instead of my system username (whoami)?

Tags: git, bash

When I type `whoami` in git bash it prints "win-me6mt62nc4m\gugl0", which is my system username. When I type `git config user.name` (using either --local, --system or --global flags) I get `goran` as the output, and `goran` is my username on the git repo I am working on.

My problem is that when I try a `git pull` it asks for gugl0`s credentials instead of goran's. How can I configure git to expect my git username instead of my system username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the config for the git remote, so add the username to the remote URL in the repo's `.git/config` file e.g.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = goran@example.com/foo/bar.git
          ^^^^^^
```

Without a username there Git will assume that the username at the remote host is the same as your local username.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks.
Before the edit, there was no reference to the git URL, but git bash knew WHERE to look, just not WHO to look for. Do you know where the URL was stored?

Comment: I realize now that I've beem staring at the .config file in my $Home folder instead of looking at the .config file inside my .git folder. I just prepended "goran@" to the [remote "origin"] value and it worked.
My final question then is: Why didn't git automatically configure this when I first cloned the repo as "goran"?